# Need INFORMATION_SCHEMA MetaData

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, information-schema

I'm trying to build a class in the tradition of Microsoft's LinqToSql code generator, only querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead. The problem I'm running into is that the metadata for INFORMATION_SCHEMA is undocumented for SQL CE. It's documented for SQL Server, but I'm not comfortable blindly doing a wholesale substitution.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174156.aspx

I've looked briefly at the code for MSLinqToSQLGenerator, but it's so complex I can't figure out where to even begin understanding how it does what it does.

How would one iterate through the columns of an INFORMATION_SCHEMA view, getting things like the data type, etc. for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool that can do this. It's called SQL Offline, by Interscape:

http://inters.com/

It returns the data type for each of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view columns.

Comment: Is this the latest news on this? I only want to know the data type of the `COLUMN_NAME` column in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table. I need this to convert a column to the data type with the right collation, the one that the system table has, so that I can union both tables on the 
`COLUMN_NAME`. Is a 10 year-old question with a tool the only trick to get this done?

Comment: They're getting at the info somehow, so obviously it's possible. It's been so long since I looked at all of this, though, that at this point I really have no idea.

Comment: I read too late that your question was about MS SQL Server ***CE***. I have overseen that when I first changed your question a bit. Now that I understood your question, I made a new one at [How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1155571/how-do-i-get-something-like-the-information-schema-columns-metadata-view-of-the) only for MS SQL Server.